# ‎Banach ‎algebra

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can you help me?

1: We know that ‎$M‎_n‎(\mathbb{‎C}) $ ‎is a‎ ‎Banach ‎algebra.

‎
 a) Can ‎we ‎say ‎the ‎set ‎of ‎all ‎upper ‎triangular(down ‎triangular) ‎is a‎ ‎subalgebra ‎of‎ ‎$ M‎_{n}‎(\mathbb{‎C}) ‎$, ‎but ‎not ‎an ideal?‎

b) ‎suppose‎ ‎$ D=\{ (a‎_{ij} )  ‎\in ‎‎‎ M‎_{n} ‎(\mathbb{‎C}) ‎:\ (a‎_{ij} )‎ =‎ 0‎ ,‎ i‎ ‎‎\neq j‎ ‎\}‎ ‎‎‎‎‎$, ‎so ‎is‎ ‎$ D $ a‎ ‎subalgebra  ‎of‎‎ ‎‎‎‎$ M‎_{n} ‎(\mathbb{‎C}) ‎$, ‎but ‎not ‎ideal?‎

2: Let‎ $\mathbb  D‎ = ‎\{‎‎‎ ‎‎\lambda ‎‎\in‎‎ ‎‎\mathbb{‎C‎}  : | ‎‎\lambda |‎ <‎ ‎1\}‎  $‎‎, 
$ ‎\mathbb  T‎ = ‎\{‎‎‎ ‎‎\lambda ‎‎\in‎‎ ‎‎\mathbb{‎C‎}  : | ‎‎\lambda |‎ =‎ ‎1\}‎  $‎‎, and‎‎ ‎$ K = \{ f \in C (‎\overline{\mathbb D}) : ‎‎\quad‎ ‎‎f(‎\lambda) =‎ 0  ,‎ ‎‎\forall‎‎ ‎\lambda ‎\in\mathbb  ‎‎  ‎T‎\}. $ ‎‎
Show ‎that‎ ‎$ K $ ‎is a‎ ‎closed  ‎ideal ‎of‎ ‎$C (‎\overline {‎\mathbb D})‎  $‎?

‎
(if‎ ‎$ ‎\Omega‎ $ is a compact Hausdorff space, the ‎set‎ ‎$ C(‎\Omega) =‎ ‎\{ f‎ :‎ ‎‎\Omega‎‎ ‎\longrightarrow‎  ‎‎\mathbb{‎C} :\ f\   \text{ is continuous on}  \Omega‎‎\}$ ‎is a‎ ‎algebra)‎

Answer (score 1):

a) Sums and products of upper triangular matrices are again upper triangular, so the set of upper triangular matrices is indeed a subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb C)$. It is not an ideal.

b) Indeed, $D$ is also a subalgebra, and also not an ideal. In fact, $M_n(\mathbb C)$ has no nontrivial two-sided ideals.

The argument for 2) is straightforward: if $f\in K$ and $g\in C(\overline{\mathbb D})$, then $(fg)(\lambda)=f(\lambda)g(\lambda)=0$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb T$, since $f(\lambda)=0$.